# Поддерживание fragment в активном состоянии

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть tabactivity, в котором находится 3 фрагмента. При переключении между этими фрагментами загружаются только соседние, а дальние убиваются. Подскажите как можно сделать так, чтобы фрагменты не убивались сами, а висели в памяти.

Comment: Если у вас ViewPager используется, то используйте его метод `setOffscreenPageLimit`

Comment: Спасибо. Так и сделал, всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не описали зачем вам это, но думаю я вас понял, и если понял я вас правильно, то вам подойдет свойство фрагмента retainInstance. Ставите его в true, и сам объект фрагмента не будет пересоздаваться, и можно использовать внутренние поля для хранения данных. Но от пересоздания вьюшек это не спасет, от этого вообще ничего не спасет, сохранять и восстанавливать их состояния придется, как ни крути